# How to export multiple Access Class objects to text from Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications at a time

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, export

I have a lot of access files that have Code Behind event procedures defined using VBA. I want to search this code for a large number of strings.

I can accomplish this by selecting the Access Class object in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications, right clicking and selecting "Export File..." then running `findstr`, but I can only export one class object at a time (it takes a very long time).

Is there a way to export multiple Access Class Objects at once, or script it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made an application that exports all the form definitions for an access file. This includes the code behind, so with the following code and a script to pull only the CodeBehind section, you can get a workable solution.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
using System;

namespace AccessExporter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();

            String fileName = @"C:\AccessFile.accdb";
            app.Visible = false;
            app.OpenCurrentDatabase(fileName);

            foreach (AccessObject obj in app.CurrentProject.AllForms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
                app.SaveAsText(AcObjectType.acForm, obj.Name, String.Format(@"C:\{0}.txt", obj.Name));
            }

            app.CloseCurrentDatabase();
        }
    }
}
```